# Does MSBuild know if a project needs to be recompiled?

Tags: msbuild, build-process

First, I  have a base assumption from watching Visual Studio compile things with its default .*proj files that, if you build the same solution twice in a row, it detects that nothing has changed and seems to fly through the solution build. Does this mean it knows that nothing was changed in a project and doesn't have to make a new DLL output?

If that's the case, I have a question. Say I have a solution with multiple class libraries, and an MSBuild task in each project that automatically increments the build's version by modifying AssemblyInfo.cs. Thing is (if my previous assumption is correct) it does this every time and triggers a new rebuild of each class library. Is there a target or property in MSBuild that can tell if the project needs recompilation, and skip my versioning step if so?

I ask because let's say I update project A, but not project B in a solution. If I run a build on the solution, I want it to update the version on project A, but since project B hasn't changed, I want to leave it alone.

Answer (score 1):

Found something: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx

> MSBuild can compare the timestamps of
>   the input files with the timestamps of
>   the output files and determine whether
>   to skip, build, or partially rebuild a
>   target. In the following example, if
>   any file in the @(CSFile) item
>   collection is newer than the hello.exe
>   file, MSBuild will run the target;
>   otherwise it will be skipped:
>
> ```
> <Csc
>     Sources="@(CSFile)" 
>     OutputAssembly="hello.exe"/> </Target>
> ```

...that worked. But then got me thinking, what if someone pulls the code down from source control without the assemblies (which is how we do it)? Since it has no output to compare against, it'll do a compile and increment the version anyway. I think the complexities might lead me to abandon this approach.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter if you increment on a developers box - what's important is that your daily/CI build is only incremented when needed. So, what I've done in the past is have some small XML file contain the next build number, and have an MSBuild task take this xml file and create a file called Version.cs (containing the versioning attributes you'd usually find in AssemblyInfo.cs).

Version.cs is never checked into your soure control - it's generated by the build.

Developers will sync the current XML file, build their binaries, and get the current version number. The continous integration build may also do the same thing. But a daily/official build will check out the XML file, increment the version information, and then check it in. From that moment on the version number has officially changed.

There are variations on this theme, but the general idea works.